# How to sort an html access log in fastest way in cpp

Tags: c++, sorting

> local - - [24/Oct/1994:13:41:41 -0600] "GET index.html HTTP/1.0" 200
>   150
>
> local - - [24/Oct/1994:13:41:41 -0600] "GET 1.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1210
>
> local - - [24/Oct/1994:13:43:13 -0600] "GET index.html HTTP/1.0" 200
>   3185
>
> remote - - [24/Oct/1994:13:43:14 -0600] "GET 2.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2555
>
> local - - [24/Oct/1994:13:43:13 -0600] "GET index.html HTTP/1.0" 200
>   32618

As in the example, I have an access log that contains around 700.000 logs in text format.

" " stands for our html page, first integer is our http reply code which will be ignored, second integer is bytes in reply that we will be using to calculate visitor numbers. Timestamps will be ignored. We will be sorting total visitor numbers for each website log as quick as possible. Which data structure method in c++ should I be using? I need some suggestion.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: For 700,000 items you should certainly be using a database.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just looking to count visitors by URL, you don't need to write a program to do this.

```
elb-logs, 515> wc -l /tmp/$$
874597 /tmp/4028

elb-logs, 516> time ( grep GET /tmp/$$ | sed -e 's/.*"GET //' | sed -e 's/ .*//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n > /tmp/example )

real    0m11.185s
user    0m13.872s
sys 0m0.476s
```

That gives me counts by URL, for GET requests. If I wanted to do something like sum up the number of bytes by URL I would use `awk`.

Admittedly, the laptop that I'm using to do this has 12 GB of RAM and an SSD, so that will affect the numbers. But even if it takes a minute to run such a command pipeline that's still a lot less time than it would take to write and debug a C++ program.